# How do I change button's size with Auto-layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I was wondering how I can change a button's size.

Example: 2x1 button when in portrait mode. 1x2 button when in landscape mode.

Can I do this in storyboard with autolayout or do I have to do this programmatically?

Comment: Yes, apply different constraint for different size class.

Comment: @gabbler How do you change size of button when orientation changes?

Comment: In Compact Width| Compact Height size class, set 1x2 button, in Compact Width | Regular size class, set 2x1 button.

Comment: @gabbler It doesn't seem to be working. I'm testing it on an iOS 8 keyboard on 5.5 inch iPhone. (wRegular hCompact)

Comment: I don't know what goes wrong, you can try just a single button, add it in any width, any height size class, and configure different width add height constraints for the button in the above two size classes.

Comment: @gabbler The only one that appears in the keyboard with changed height is wAny hAny.

Comment: Here is an example :https://www.dropbox.com/s/3118m6p6u1qfy0i/ButtonTest.zip?dl=0, it has different width in different mode, I can't write a keyboard to reproduce it, that's too much work for me.

Comment: @gabbler I think I see the problem now. It works when I go to attributes and add it to "installed" at the bottom. But this messes up other constraints a little (everything slid to half way right)

Answer (score 0):

While adding button,just add

```
[self.view addSubView self.tableButton];
```

and in

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

[self.tableConstraintWidth autoRemove];
[self.tableConstraintLeft autoRemove];
[self.tableConstraintHeight autoRemove];
[self.tableConstraintTop autoRemove];

//Assign again with different constraints depending on the orientation

Check orientation

if(Landscape) {

self.tableConstraintLeft = Left constraint
self.tableConstraintTop = Top Constraint
self.tableConstraintWidth = Width Constraint
self.tableConstraintHeight = Height Constraint

}else {

self.tableConstraintLeft = Left constraint
self.tableConstraintTop = Top Constraint
self.tableConstraintWidth = Width Constraint
self.tableConstraintHeight = Height Constraint

 }

}
```